# How to add data table length ,pagination and html button into the single row at the top and bottom at right side of the page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add length pagination and Html button on the top and bottom of the table using data table but am not able to align it into the single row.
can anyone help me to align datatable control to a single row?

**required**: want to show page info in before the table header and after footer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code or create fiddle .

Comment: Please provide relevant details about your question ,add a code snippet atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var info = table.page.info();

$('#tableInfo').html(
    'Currently showing page '+(info.page+1)+' of '+info.pages+' pages.'
);
```

Hope this will helps you.
For more details visit,

[page.info()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info())